# Powershell -match -replace producing duplicate lines in output

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell.  I am trying to do multiple replaces on text in a file, but I am getting duplicate lines.  My test file has the following lines:

```
This is a test.
There is a test.
```

I run the following script:

```
(Get-Content "C:\temp\test.txt") | 
    foreach-object {

            if ($_ -match "This"){
                $_ -replace "This" , "That"
            }

            if ($_ -match "test"){
                $_ -replace "test" , "toast"
            }

    } | Set-Content "C:\temp\test.txt"
```

My output should be:

```
That is a toast.
There is a toast.
```

But it is outputting separate lines for the replacements on the first line in the input:

```
That is a test.
This is a toast.
There is a toast.
```

As you can see, between the two lines, the second line only meets one of the "match" criteria and is properly replaced.  However, the first line is output twice -- one for each replace.  I need the script to only output this line once if the line matches both conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy why you are getting 3 lines of output. First object is `'This is a test'` and that matches the first `if`, so it will replace `'This'` with `'That'` and outputs `That is a test`. Then, the first object also matches the second `if` because there is a `'test'`, so it also outputs `'This is a toast'`. Finally the second object only matches the second `if` so it outputs `'There is a toast'`. Hence the 3 lines of output.

When you type `$_ -replace 'x','y'` it returns another object, it doesn't change $_. If you are writing a script go ahead on put it on multiple lines and make it do what you want.

```
$file = Get-Content $path
foreach($line in $file){
    if($line -match 'This'){
        $line = $line -replace 'This','That'
    }
    if($line -match 'test'){
        $line = $line -replace 'test','toast'
    }
    $line
}
```

Comment: Although @mjolinor does provide the answer to solve my example question, this one solves my underlying problem and my misunderstanding of the use of $_

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way:

```
(Get-Content "C:\temp\test.txt") -replace 'This','That' -replace 'test','toast' | Set-Content "C:\temp\test.txt"
```

Comment: I need to do a replace only when the match conditions are met.  Occassionally a single line will meet both conditions and output the two lines, when I only need one line with both replacements.  I will update my question to be more specific.

Comment: Are you saying you only want to do the replacement if the input line matches both 'This' and 'test'?

Comment: I have updated my question again to address this.  If a line matches two conditions, I need both replaces to output one line rather than outputting two separate lines.

Comment: Did you test the solution I posted?  I believe that should meet those requirements.